# Preg_match: get last two domain segments from url in one expression

Tags: php, regex, url, dns, preg-match

There is an example on php.net how to get last two domain segments in two steps:

```
    <?php 
 //get host name from URL
preg_match("/^(http:\/\/)?([^\/]+)/i",
    "http://www.php.net/index.html", $matches);
$host = $matches[2];

// get last two segments of host name
preg_match("/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/", $host, $matches);
echo "domain name is: {$matches[0]}\n";

/* Output is php.net */

?>
```

But how can I do it in one step, using only one preg_match expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This piece of code:

```
$domain = 'http://www.php.net/index.html';
$url    = parse_url($domain);
$tokens = explode('.', $url['host']);

print_r($tokens);
```

Will give you this data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => www
    [1] => php
    [2] => net
)
```

I believe there is no need for regexs as far as it's very hard to properly parse URL with them. From resulting $tokens array you can extract any part of host name easily.

Update:

```
print_r($url);
```

$url array contains all necessary details:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.php.net
    [path] => /index.html
)
```

Comment: Yes it will. But I need the result from preg_match. To get http://www.php.net/index.html -> php.net in just one regex.

Comment: Thank you, parse_url is sure the easiest way to get the domain, but can I do the same thing using only one regex?

Comment: You can do it with regex of course, and i believe there are some ready to use expressions, though due to complexity of URIs it's very hard to parse all kind of URLs with regexs.

Comment: @TarasBulgakov i just looked inside PHP source code, and builtin filter extension uses this method for validating URL. In past versions there was one huge regex, in current stable sources this regex logic is entirely removed.