# How to detect if user input is a domain?

Tags: php, preg-match

I am writing some code for my website and I need to find out a way to detect a user's input and determine whether or not it is a domain or an IP. If it is a domain it will then parse the domain from e.g. `http://www.google.com` to `google.com`, then resolve it and echo it back into the user input field. If it is a IP then it will skip all of these steps and remain in the IP user input field.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
if( $_POST['submit'] )
{
    $ip_address=$_POST["host"];

    if (ctype_alpha($ip_address)) 
    {
        // get host name from URL
        preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i', $ip_address, $matches);
        $host = $matches[1];

        // get last two segments of host name
        preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $host, $matches);
        $new_ip_address = $matches;

        //resolve parsed ip
        $presolved = gethostbyname($new_ip_address);
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Do stuff.\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't think the presence of `http://` (or lack of) will matter with IP addresses, unless this is purely for display on a webpage - the browser will assume that protocol. Also, what about `https`?

Comment: @Michael love it! user2934716 you should look at the accepted answer on that question too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11046121/2812842

Comment: I would use a regular expression similar to `(?:^.*?//)?(.*?)[:/]?` to capture the "probable domain name". This should match `foo.com` from `http://foo.com:80`, `//foo.com`, `foo.com/bar`, etc. If `foo.com` doesn't happen to resolve to an IP or they "accidentally left of a sub-domain" then .. oh, well: you tried to help.

Comment: (Also, not all registered domains are wired to IPs: "whois" might be needed in some cases.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered looking at it from the other direction?  Detecting an IP address literal is much easier than parsing and validating a DNS name.

1. Parse the URL with [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
2. Split `$url['host']` by `'.'`.  If the result is an array of four integer elements, then it is probably an IP address.
3. Bonus points for checking that each integer is in the appropriate range (e.g, 1-255 for the first octet and 0-255 for the remaining octets).

In any case, use `parse_url` instead of trying to crack this with the regex hammer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://php.net/filter_var

```
var_dump(filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED));
```

Comment: APPLIES TO ALL ANSWERS SO FAR: I'm confused, am I suppose to change all of what I have to that or which part?

Answer (score 0):

To check if the input was an ip, you can use php's `ip2long` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php)

See the example below, which will return an IP or false.

```
<?php
function checkOrMakeIp($address) {
    $long = ip2long($address);
    if ($long != -1 || $long !== FALSE) {
       // It is a IP, just return the address
       return $address;
    } elseif($ip = gethostbynamel($address)) {
       // It is a hostname, but now we have the ip, return it
       return $ip[0];
    }

    return false;
}
?>
```

Notice the `gethostbynamel`, it will return FALSE if the hostname could not be resolved; otherwise an array. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php)

Comment: This seems to be what I am after, but I can't get it to work. Do you have an email or something where you could provide me with further assistance?