# Remove a domain from url with preg_match or some sort of method

Tags: php, preg-match

So i have this code like this

```
http://vid.cdn.domainname.com/_videos_t4vn23s9jc5498tgj49icfj4678/0000430/_mp4/0430303.mp4
```

This is video file that i get from link and i can use this file to stream it on my site

But problem is that domain name is not always the same from link i get, but domain name is always the same for stream files.

So i need to remove

```
http://vid.cdn.domainname.com/
```

from url with preg_match or some sort of method and only left with a link to video file like this

```
_videos_t4vn23s9jc5498tgj49icfj4678/0000430/_mp4/0430303.mp4
```

i guess preg_match would be the method to use but im not sure. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I found sort of the answer here [Preg_match: get last two domain segments from url in one expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046066/preg-match-get-last-two-domain-segments-from-url-in-one-expression) but im not sure if it will always work i have to test it a bit more.

Comment: Use [parse_url](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the path. Use a regex when you need one and *don't* when you don't.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = preg_replace('~http://[^/]+/~', '', $str);
```